# Php File For HTML Php form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am studying on a site template for quite long. I have a contact form in my site and my html file (index.html) is linked to a js file (contact-me.js). I'm providing them below :

Contact Form In index.html :

```
<!-- OPEN - Content -->
            <div class="item-title text-center">

                <!-- Contact form -->
                <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="POST" data-name="Contact Form">

                    <div class="row">

                        <!-- Full name -->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" id="name" class="form form-control" placeholder="Write your name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Write your name'" name="name" data-name="Name" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- E-mail -->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" id="email" class="form form-control" placeholder="Write your email address" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Write your email address'" name="email-address" data-name="Email Address" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Subject -->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" id="subject" class="form form-control" placeholder="Write the subject" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Write the subject'" name="subject" data-name="Subject">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Message -->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 no-padding">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea id="text-area" class="form textarea form-control" placeholder="Your message here... 20 characters Min." onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Your message here... 20 characters Min.'" name="message" data-name="Text Area" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <!-- Button submit -->
                    <button type="submit" id="valid-form" class="btn btn-color">Send my Message</button>

                </form>
                <!-- /. Contact form -->

                <div id="block-answer">
                    <div id="answer"></div>
                </div>

            </div> <!-- CLOSE - Content -->
```

and my contact-me.js is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#contact-form [type='submit']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get input field values of the contact form
    var user_name       = $('input[name=name]').val();
    var user_email      = $('input[name=email-address]').val();
    var user_subject    = $('input[name=subject]').val();
    var user_message    = $('textarea[name=message]').val();

    // Datadata to be sent to server
    post_data = {'userName':user_name, 'userEmail':user_email, 'userSubject':user_subject, 'userMessage':user_message};

    // Ajax post data to server
    $.post('php/contact-me.php', post_data, function(response){  

        // Load json data from server and output message    
        if(response.type == 'error') {

            output = '<div class="error-message"><p>'+response.text+'</p></div>';

        } else {

            output = '<div class="success-message"><p>'+response.text+'</p></div>';

            // After, all the fields are reseted
            $('#contact-form input').val('');
            $('#contact-form textarea').val('');

        }

        $("#answer").hide().html(output).fadeIn();

    }, 'json');

});

// Reset and hide all messages on .keyup()
$("#contact-form input, #contact-form textarea").keyup(function() {
    $("#answer").fadeOut();
});

});
```

Can You Please Help Me With The php file. I am completely new to php. Please help me with the php file that I should use for this form.

Comment: What type of php help? What have you tried which not worked ?

Comment: actually I need the contents of the php file contact-me.php

Comment: Your question not clear sir

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code.
You need a basic understanding of [POST and GET method](https://www.formget.com/php-post-get/) and read [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) on how to use 'mail()'

```
<?php
    $to = "mail@yourdomain.com"; 
    $from = $_POST['user_email']; 
    $name = $_POST['user_name']; 
    $headers = "From: $from"; 
    $subject = $_POST['user_subject']; 
    $body = $_POST['user_message']; 
    $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you need a php script to send you the data  on your mail that user enters

I seriously have no idea why you are using Javascript(you are not verifying data,so use post action method of php. just add action="somename.php" in form tag,somewat like this

```html
 <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="POST" action="somename.php">
```

and in somename.php keep the following content

```html
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$usermail = $_POST['email-address'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$to = "yourmail@example.com";
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$text = "Name-" . $name ."\nEmail-" . $usermail ."\nMessage-" . $message;
$headers = "From: webmaster@yourdomain.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

mail($to,$subject,$text,$headers);

?>
```

You may continue using javascript(if so dont add action to form tag).